# Function to sort a list of tuples - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Sorry for the easy question it's just I'm extremely new to haskell..

I'm trying to write a function "order" which will sort a list of tuples produced by another function "frequency" (frequency counts the number of distinct elements in a list a gives one such result, say > frequency "aabbbccc", would incur the result, [(2,a),(3,b),(3,c)]) into ascending order. I can't work out how to write it.

If I write >sort (frequency score) into the prelude it will sort it (score being a list of grades, i.e ["a", "b", "c", "c"].

But when I try to write a function..

```
results :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
results = sort (frequency score)
```

It sadly does not work saying that sort is applied to too many arguments.

Sorry for the obvious question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to make your function take an argument.

```
results :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
results score = sort (frequency score)
```

Without it, the compiler sees your type signature and infers that in order to return something of type `[a] -> [(Int, a)]`, `sort` must take another argument, which it doesn't.

However, the next problem is then that you can't sort a list of tuples with arbitrary component types. See @luqui's answer for how to deal with that.

Comment: Note that with `sort`, an `Ord` constraint on `a` is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it says `sort` is applied too many arguments?  To me, it looks like you have given the wrong type signature.  This may work easily:

```
results :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
```

(i.e. you can't sort a list of `[(Int, a)]` unless `a` is a type that has an `Ord`ering, that is you can compare elements).

However, this signature is not really necessary, you could also `sortBy (\x y -> compare (fst x) (fst y))`, which has a number of idiomatic succinct ways of it, but for newbies I think it's better to be explicit.  This way does not need to compare `a`s, as it only looks at the `Int`s.

**Edit**: oh yeah, I see why it would say `sort` is applied too many arguments. See @hammar's answer.